# Core Data creating new UIView from textfield with filter NSPredicate

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, nspredicate

I have some problems how to implement creating new view from selected database and it attribute group. In my app all resources(data) are shown in mainviewController.xib. In second viewController I have textfields to add data to my base. On of this textfield is group. I want to add new view when I write a new group to my base. When my group name is the same which is in my actual base I do nothing. Here I give some code which I use. In my code is grupa as group. This code is from second view.

```
- (IBAction) saveData
{
    NSLog(@"saveData");
    [self dismissKeyboard];
    Destination *dest = (Destination *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Destination" 
                                                                     inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    dest.nazwa = nazwaTextField.text;
    dest.zasob = zasobTextField.text;
    dest.grupa = grupaTextField.text;
    dest.typzasobu = typzasobuTextField.text;
    dest.tag = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[_arrayLogics indexOfObject:typzasobuTextField.text]];

    NSError *error;

    // here's where the actual save happens, and if it doesn't we print something out to the console
    if (![managedObjectContext save:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Problem saving: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }

    // **** log objects currently in database ****
    // create fetch object, this object fetch's the objects out of the database
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Destination" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    for (NSManagedObject *info in fetchedObjects)
    {
        NSLog(@"Nazwa Zasobu: %@", [info valueForKey:@"nazwa"]);
        NSLog(@"Zasób: %@", [info valueForKey:@"zasob"]);
        NSLog(@"Grupa: %@", [info valueForKey:@"grupa"]);
        NSLog(@"Typ zasobu: %@", [info valueForKey:@"typzasobu"]);
    }


    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Potwierdzenie" message:@"Zasób zapisany" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];   

}
```

thanks

Comment: Are you asking how to add a textfield to a view?

Comment: No, I have all the texfields add to view.

Comment: ...are you asking how to add a view to a view controller? I'm not quite following your question.

Comment: I want to generate (create) new view connected with new group which I add to my base.

Comment: And connect it to slide for example with page control./

Comment: I'm having some trouble understanding your request, but I think you want something like a navigation controller? Where you can have multiple views and move between them (back and forth).

Comment: I want to make new view in main viewController which switches between another with page control. I use Core Data to store my resources. I one textfield I add groups. I want to connect this new view with this group. That'sall

Comment: To switch views in a view controller, you need to instantiate the view `UIView *viewName = [/*UIView creation code*/]`. Then just do `self.view = viewName`. Store a reference to your old view too and do the same thing to switch back.

Comment: You don't understand my questions, but thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* I understand...

- You have a list of resouces (Zasób) on your primary view.
- **These resources are grouped by the 'Grupa' field.**
- You have another viewController where you can add / edit resources.

Correct me if I'm wrong but I think you want your main view to look very much like this:
[image]

If this is correct I would advise that look into [UITableViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)'s and  [UITableView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/UITableViewStyleGrouped) with the table style of [UITableViewStyleGrouped](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/UITableViewStyleGrouped). This way you can add / edit a list of resource the way Apple recommends.

The flow would look something like this:
[image]

You'll need to learn about [NSSortDescriptor's](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSortDescriptor_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (to order your fetches from the datastore), and how to plug in your table's [data source](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) & [delegate methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) but it's worth it

Here are some resources to help you acquire knowledge:

- [Basic UITableVIew Tutorial](http://kurrytran.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/ios-5-storyboard-uitableview-tutorial.html)
- [Apple's guidelines about table views](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html)